# Registration: Email hash and verifying only one account per email

Tags: php, sql, email, optimization

I'm using a registration function that hashes the email in PBKDF2 with a random and unique Salt each time. The hashes email and his salt are saved in the DB. No problem with that.
The problem is that now I want to make sure that users only create one single account per email. Obviously to verify that I need to check my DB and that's where the problem starts. I either lose in security or in time.

Because as I see it I have 2 choices:

1 - I change my hash method and use a common Salt for all emails. Which make me lose a bit of security.

Or

2 - I hash the email with all the Salts from the DB and check for matches. My guess is that this will be horribly slow.

So my question are:

- What should I do? Optimize security or "time"?
- Maybe hashing emails with unique and random salts in PBKDF2 is too much? If yes, what hashing method should I use?
- Is there any other solution?

PS: I didn't post any code because I think this is more of a theory discussion but if code is needed let me know, I will add it.

Comment: Is there a reason why you need to hash the email address?

Comment: Well if someone hack the DB, I don't want the users emails to be compromise

Comment: That's fair enough.

Comment: But if you're hashing the email, you can't retrieve them. So why store them?

Comment: If he wants to check for email-uniqueness he would need to store them.  I assume he doesn't need to use them for anything other than this purpose?

Comment: I need to store them somehow to make sure users only create one account per email. And I can't retrieve them but I can compare an hash to another hash and if they are the same then the input was the same.

Comment: It seems like a security step too far. Why not just use a username and store it in plain text?

Comment: @catshoes, yep. I only need to send a confirmation email but that is done before the hashing, so no problem.

Comment: @pete, store the email in plain text?

Comment: @pete I don't think it is a security step too far.  You're just running into the No Free Lunch theorem in this situation.  However, the common salt option might be the better of your two posted options. IMHO

Comment: @user1606963 No. Use the email to send out confirmation but ask for a username e.g. Pete - and store the username in plain text.

Comment: One option that just crossed my mind... Use an extra table USED_EMAILS that stores a list of email addresses used. This way they are not associated with specific users.  Does not really help with the hashing, however.

Comment: You may want to *encrypt* rather than *hash*. There's a big difference, OP. Then, in order to verify only one account per email, make that column unique.

Comment: @Matt I think he actually wants to hash...

Comment: @arxanas uniqueness may be moot after a certain number of accounts if OP uses a hash. Collisions and such (not likely with the proper hash, I know, but still possible).

Comment: @pete, sure. I only talked about the email part of the registration process. I also use a unique username saved in plain text, but I don't want users to create 100 accounts with the same emails. The problem is the email =/

Comment: @user1606963 make both the `username` and `email` columns `unique`.

Comment: @Matt The emails are hashed *and* salted: a unique email field won't do much.

Comment: @arxanas hence my suggestion to encrypt.

Comment: @catshoes, ya but if someone hack the DB they will get all the plain text emails =/

Comment: @Matt, hashing seems more secure than encrypting.

Comment: Potato, po-tah-to. If you never want to be able to see/use the email addresses again, go with a hash. However, I'm sure you may want to email your users every once in awhile. You'll need a way to decrypt those email addresses, and a hash won't allow you to do that. You're allowing security to outweigh usefulness. It's like locking a fire extinguisher in a safe that requires 3 people's PIN codes to open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Store a clear-text 'digest' of each email address alongside the hashed actual email. The digest should contain enough information to bring the number of candidates down to a reasonable handful (I'd say a factor of 1000 or more isn't unrealistic), but not enough to guess the entire email address. For example, you could use the first two characters from the user part of the address, two characters from the domain name, and the TLD part; this would turn 'john.doe@example.org' into 'jo@ex.org'.

Finding collisions now becomes a two-step process: first, find all entries with matching digests, then do the actual hash comparison only on those. Instead of downloading all hashes from the DB for each check, you pre-filter them down to about 1/1000. That is a significant improvement, and while you trade *some* security for it, it's better than either alternative.

Comment: Very nice solution. That's seems the best compromise IMO. I loose a little bit of security but I can keep the random salts and there not much someone can do with the digest emails anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to merely protect the emails, a simple hashing algorithm is all that is required. There is no point in even adding a random salt for making the system more secure, as you are not storing sensitive information.

For most hashing algorithms, the chance for a collision is negligent. So no two emails should be able to create the same hash. That way, you just need to make that column unique to detect duplicate emails.